# Example of logic (concept) that can not be embedded (expressed) in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: logic, math-software, meta-math, metalogic

Tutorial for Isabelle/HOL https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/tutorial.pdf states that:

> HOL can express most mathematical concepts, and functional
>   programmingis just one particularly simple and ubiquitous instance.

What is the example of concept that can not be expressed (reasoned) in Isabelle/HOL? What is the example of logic that can not be embedded (expressed) in Isabelle/HOL?

I am trying to use Isabelle/HOL for implementing artificial general intelligence and I would like to comprehend the possible bounds of the framework.